# Abrir Aplicativo automaticamente pelo navegador Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estava fazendo um Script de automacao web com *Selenium/Python*.

E uma das etapa é abrir o aplicativo:

[image: open Pick App]

Estou usando Biblioteca do **Selenium** (*Python*)

Pesquisei um pouco e descubri que ele nao é um `alert` e metodo como `alert.accept()` nao funciona.

Achei uma solucao usando `keyboard` mas ele necessita que a janela precisa estar focada:

```
keyboard.press_and_release('left, enter')
```

Se eu marcar a caixa: " *Always open these types of links in the associated app* "

O navegador nao salva essa opcao e proxima vez que executar o Scripts o navegador pergunta novamente se quero abrir o app.

Teria alguma solucao de ele abrir app automaticamente sem precisar estar focada na janela do navegador?

Comment: Cara, se eu não me engano esse tipo de alerta não é bem do navegador, é algo aberto pelo teu SO com o template do browser , isso é muito parecido quando vai selecionar um certificado digital. Uma opção seria tu importar as configurações do teu navegador.

Answer (score -2):

Esse alerta está na camada do sistema operacional, não propriamente no navegador. Então, pelo que pesquisei, o selenium não reconhece. O que você pode fazer é utilizar o pyautogui: https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/

Tirar um print do botão "Open pick an app" e programar o pyautogui navegar com o mouse até esse botão e clicar. Se você der uma pesquisada você vai encontrar bastante conteúdo ensinando sobre.

Comment: Apenas complementando, função do pyautogui `pyautogui.locateonscreen('path print')` e usa um while true para esperar ele achar e clickar